# Fix \parbox on upper bound of \makebox

Tags: vertical-alignment, titles, boxes

right now I'm designing the titlepage for my thesis. The logo of my university should be in the upper left corner, then I want a vertical line starting at the top of the logo and ending at the bottom of the page. In the lower right corner should be more text.

I tried to realize this with nested boxes. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
      \newgeometry{margin=2cm, headheight = 0cm, centering=true}
      \fbox{
        \makebox[\textwidth]{
          \parbox[b]{0.3819\textwidth}{
                \hspace{0.01\textwidth}\hspace{1em}\vbox{%
                    \raggedright
                    \rule{0.85\linewidth}{3cm}

                }
            }%

            \rule{1pt}{0.99\textheight}

            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6181\textwidth}
                \begin{minipage}[b]{10cm}%{%
                    \raggedleft
                {\noindent\Large Text}\\[\baselineskip]
                \end{minipage}
          \end{minipage}  
        }%outer makebox
      }
    \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

It's pretty obvious, that the rule is the problem. Can someone help me? Thanks, FFoDWindow

Comment: If you change the vertical rule to `\rule[\dimexpr-.99\textheight+3cm\relax]{1pt}{0.99\textheight}`, the logo goes to the top.  However, I couldn't say if the text is where you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can vastly simplify the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\newgeometry{margin=2cm, headheight = 0cm}%,headsep=0pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\vspace*{-\topskip}
\vspace*{-\fboxrule}

\hspace*{-\fboxrule}%
\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}[t][\textheight]{0.3819\textwidth}
    \centering
    \vspace{0pt}% set the reference point to the top
    \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\textwidth-2em]{example-image}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hspace{-.5pt}\vrule width 1pt\hspace*{-.5pt}%
  \begin{minipage}[t][\dimexpr\textheight-.4pt][b]{0.6181\textwidth}
  \raggedleft
  \Large Text

  \vspace*{\baselineskip}
  \end{minipage}%
}% end of \fbox
\hspace*{-\fboxrule}

\vspace*{-\fboxrule}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's working well, thank you! I'll use your code, so I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `tikz`-package you could create your titlepage like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\newgeometry{margin=2cm, headheight = 0cm, centering=true}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,yshift=-2cm,xshift=2cm] at (current page.north west)
    {\rule{0.3819\linewidth}{3cm}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{0.3819\linewidth}\rule{1pt}{0.99\textheight}
\parbox[t]{0.6181\textwidth}{\raggedleft\Large Text}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is still this a small gap between the upper edge of the logo and the end of the rule.

Comment: @FFoDWindow then I misinterpretted your question. I won't adapt the answer because of egreg's solving your problem.